# Caed Nua - People seeking employment

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

In my Caed Nua log, it shows there is a guy seeking employment. I simply can't find the guy or a way to hire him through the Caed Nua interface. How is it done?

Comment: Full original message could be helpful in finding what exactly you are seeing. Also, do you have Barracks built?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the barracks built, then you just need to wait a little before the employment is possible. There is a little time shift between the log interface and the hiring interface. spend a night or change maps and it will do the trick.